# What should you do when the IT department just copy paste emails and then assign the ticket to you?

Tags: management, behavior, attitude

What should you do when the IT department just copy paste emails and then assign the ticket to you?

I noticed they just copy paste the email they receive and they don't make an effort to solve them by themselves and just assign the ticket to me.

As a result, most of the tickets are duplicates and 50% of them are tickets they could have solved without a programmer taking care of it.

Comment: What exactly is your role? You imply that you're a programmer by your last sentence, but even taking hat into account we still don't really know what you're supposed to be doing

Comment: If most of the tickets could be resolved without a programmer, then IT sending them to you should be a logical output?

Comment: A lot of answers seem to know what the OP should do without even knowing the OP's role in the organisation. Amazing!

Comment: @GregoryCurrie - You mean it's confusing that 50 users upvoted a comment asking the author what their role is exactly, and not a single person (or not enough) of those users flagged this question due to the fact it's very difficult to answer without knowing the author's exact role?

Comment: @Donald I would have though a few answers with: "If your role is X" would have made sense, but everyone seems to assume the OP has the authority to enact change.

Comment: This probably should not have been closed.  This question is pretty clear as is, about as much as any other question on this site.  I've flagged it to ask a moderator if it can be reopened.

Answer (score 143):

Sounds to me as though they're missing out the fairly important step of triaging the tickets before assigning them to you. Let's be frank the most likely explanation for this is good old fashioned laziness on their part, you know it, I know it. However going straight at the problem with the "IT are just being lazy/work-shy" and sloping it all off on to me" might not be most sensible approach.

What you need to do is get all your bases covered so that management come to that conclusion on their own and take the appropriate measures.

So..

> 50% of them are tickets they could have solved without a programmer taking care of it.

Make sure that the resources (documentation etc) they need to solve these cases a) exists b) is up to date and c) is readily available. If it is then start bouncing these tickets back to them - provide a link on where they can find the answer as you do. As much as possible resist the (perfectly natural) urge to snark when you do so, you aren't remonstrating with them you're *helping* them!

Do nothing that actually *solves* the ticket or otherwise works it, you just want to put the ball in their court but in such a way that no-one can suggest you aren't being helpful or constructive, even if doing this initially costs you just as much time and effort as solving the darn thing yourself because the goal is to get them engaging with the tickets rather than just copy-pasting.

If you can make it so that they have to engage because you don't just take care of them you'll deny them the zero-effort option, and if you can get it so that solving the tickets themselves is effort-neutral with trying to get you to do them all the better.

> most of the tickets are duplicates

Every time you get a dupe bounce it back with a link to the duplicate target, if the original has the "answer" on it, either on the ticket itself or as a link to the docs (as above) then all the better.

For both of these make a record **every single time** - if it costs you any significant time record that too. Because if they *don't* respond to the above tactics in a week or two then you've then got ready-made hard numbers about the unnecessary impact on you that you can take to your manager and say *"I had to spend time on X tickets last week, Y were duplicates of already resolved issues, Z were things that is already covered in the docs and required no coding this is causing me disruption/delays on my programming tasks A,B and C"*.

Your manager (hopefully) knows that the company is paying you to write code - not do service desk admin and that they already pay some people to do that.

Your manager may well ask *"Do they (IT) know where these solutions/docs are?"* and you can respond positively, stress that you've reminded them each time and pointed it out and you head off any "let's try and educate them" phase because you've already done it.

Comment: This answer is great because it also addresses OP's feelings, and  why nothing is gained by acting on these feelings.

Comment: This matches my experience in every place I've ever worked

Comment: Absolutely. Engaging with the service desk employees in a way that puts you both "on the same team" leaves the option of friendly resolution open for as long as possible.

Comment: Making sure documentation & operations guides are useful and up-to-date, and providing these to the IT team, are key tasks here which will benefit everybody. And providing links to relevant materials/ tickets (eg. dup tickets) in emails shows what professionalism looks like.

Comment: Great answer. How do you get less confident / underpaid /  lazy employees to follow a process - make it the easiest option for them ....

Comment: I love this answer.  A couple of things to add:  Devs should be **THIRD** level support. 1st being the script-punchers, the 2nd the advanced techs doing diagnostics.  Escalations from each level should not exceed 20%.  As in each level should be able to solve 80% of the tickets they receive **WITHOUT** escalating to the level above them.

Comment: The last three paragraphs are the most important here. In most organizations, they don't care if you're annoyed. They do care if they're paying twice as much for the same work, and chances are a dev costs much more than your IT tech.

Comment: IT could be bouncing the tickets over because its not within their realm of responsibility. I get many tickets assigned that could be handled by a different level of support but the SOPs and siloed responsibilities don't allow for the lower tier to resolve even if they know how.

Answer (score 8):

I suggest you speak with your manager, and point out, over the average week or month, how much effort you've spent dealing with tickets that didn't require you to solve them.  Let you manager know that this was time you could have better spent accomplishing the goals that they had set out for you.

Either you manager is okay with your effort going to these tasks, or he or she isn't.   If you manager isn't okay with this, let him or her solve this issue.

Comment: Every organization using a bugtracker or other ticket system should have guidelines how to use it. Work with your manager to define a foolproof process how a ticket needs to be crafted and handled before it reaches the devs. In our organization, we have a software tester assigned to going through the created tickets, looking for duplicates and bouncing back insufficient described issues to the reporter. After getting the 3rd ticket thrown back in his face, even the laziest IT guy will start thinking before creating a ticket.

Answer (score 5):

I've used systems before where one of the required fields on the ticket (or one of the data points that was required to be in the details) was a description of all previous troubleshooting that had been done.  The primary purpose of that field was to prevent the ticket assignee from doing something that was already tried unsuccessfully.  It's a waste of time for everybody, and users feel ignored when 5 different people all ask them to try the same thing.  Not to mention, solving the ticket using developer time is usually a lot more expensive than using first-level IT support staff time.

That system had the beneficial side effect of preventing the sort of lazy task-dumping that you describe.  If a copy-paste ticket like that came in, we'd immediately kick it back to the submitter as missing information.  That would force one of three things to happen:

1. The submitter does the troubleshooting work that they should have done in the first place. After a few tickets, they start to see that it would be less work for them to troubleshoot the tickets the first time around, and the problem solves itself.
2. They modify the ticket and indicate that they did no work.  This creates a nice, easy to follow paper trail that management can see and act on.
3. They lie on the ticket and act like they tried troubleshooting it.  You'll spot this happening as you resolve tickets by doing things that supposedly failed earlier.  Keep track of such tickets and who they came from, and let your manager know that you wasted time on X# of tickets that by all accounts should have been resolved by the ticket submitter.  Either the submitter is lying, or they're not doing the troubleshooting correctly.

Having a reliable way to quickly kick these sorts of tickets back to the submitter is important.  One of the big reasons you see this behavior is when IT departments are evaluated based on how many tickets they have open and how old they are.  By dumping tickets on you, it makes their metrics look better (yet another reason these sorts of metrics are awful).  If those tickets almost immediately end up back in their lap, you are no longer a reliable ticket dumping ground and there's no longer any benefit in not doing the work that they're supposed to be doing.  You can even query your work tracking system for "tickets in the last month that went from 'New' to 'Missing Information' state within 24 hours" to track whether the problem is getting better or worse.

Answer (score 4):

First step is always communication, it solves most problems. I think you should go and have a talk with the persons in IT. Don't accuse anyone, just have a friendly chat. Assume it's some sort of miscommunication. Bring one of the tickets and try to figure out why they assign it to you instead of solving it themselves.

When doing this it helps if you can physically go and talk to them, if that's not possible a video call might work. Text messages or email won't work since it's really hard to be open and not seem accusatory. Don't book a meeting for it, since that might get very official and get people to be defensive. It's important that everyone feels secure, it's about improving and not blaming.

If this doesn't work it's time to use the suggestions in the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

Tickets should cause an action. Email from customer should often *not* cause any development action. If 99 people are happy with the current state and one isn’t, you will get *one* email requesting a change, which will make 99 people unhappy.

And most customers are not very good at telling you what exactly their problem is. At that point your company needs to decide whose job it is to get from an email to an actionable ticket.

Comment: And then there are those users who want to specify *how* the goal should be reached, without realizing they have no background in making good choices in UX.

Comment: Agree with "email from customer should often not cause any development action", exception being I think obvious bugs. I'm not saying the dev should just what is basically a forwarded email though.

Comment: @donjuedo There's a real art in discovering what a user's _actual_  need is — since it's often _very_ different from what they ask for… (It can be really important to have a good understanding of the user's point of view, work, and business area. Users don't have the IT mind-set, and so you need to bridge that gap somehow.)

Answer (score -1):

I really like @Motosubatsu's answer.  As someone that used to manage a global team of support engineers and developers, I'll share what worked for me.  The policy was that, unless it was something completely obscure, we would never, ever answer a support ticket directly.  Instead, we would create a document/knowledgebase article and provide the link or document as an answer to to the ticket.  It took only slightly longer to produce the document than to answer the request directly, but the answer could be provided over and over again.  When we grew or replaced members on a team, we weren't relying on tribal knowledge but instead a comprehensive repository of documentation that team members could draw upon.  After a few years, we had thousands of documents covering everything from what version of our software resolved bugs to how-to articles for scenarios that weren't covered in the manual.

A similar approach could be useful in your case.  Instead of providing the answer and resolving the item yourself, use it as an opportunity to identify where additional documentation is needed.  Don't expect people to go out and read it (you are setting yourself up for disappointment), but it does give you the ability to either provider a link to the documents, or simply respond back to IT with a simple "this is covered in the documentation" comment.  Managers generally dislike when their employees take time to give others the tools to do their jobs efficiently, and those tools get ignored.

Another facet of this is that, if you are getting that many duplicate tickets, it could indicate an issue with the software itself... brittle code or a feature that is not as intuitive as it needs to be.  Software that produces mountains of support requests is poorly designed.  If you want to possibly win some points, collect up some metrics and talk to your manager about a solution.  "Boss, over the last two weeks I've spent 13 hours responding to 81 tickets regarding the Foo Configurator.  I'd like to spend some time in the next sprint fixing the errors/improving usability so we give the users a better experience.  This is how I think I can make it better..."

Your problem has more than one contributor.  You can't directly control how IT handles the tickets, but you are absolutely in control of how you choose to respond to them landing on your desk, and probably at least some control over the code that produces the tickets in the first place.  Do the things that are within your power to reduce the amount of tickets heading your way and your life should improve.

As a final note, as someone who has been in both roles, I've rarely known a developer that doesn't have unrealistic expectations of what people should intrinsically know.  Remember, while an application is a significant portion of your life, it may only be a tiny portion of what someone in a different role has to know/support.  If you focus on writing solid code and features that are intuitive, and giving those supporting it great tools, you'll make friends and produce good outcomes.

Answer (score -1):

A lot of other answers seem to go into great details about how things are "meant to work", obviously with no understanding about the operational requirements of the company you work for and the power structures at play.

I suspect you personally don't really have much power in this situation.

If that is the case, and you suspect your time is getting needlessly wasted, you should speak to your manager. They may:

- Agree with you, and work with the IT department to rectify
- Agree with you, and ask you to work with the IT department to rectify
- Agree with you, and ask you to draft up a better process
- Agree with you, and tell you some other way to handle the situation
- Agree with you, but regrettably state that the IT department don't have the resources to triage
- Agree with you, but regrettably state they lack the political power to enact the change
- Disagree with you
- Be interested, and ask your to collect information so you can quantify wasted time
- Ignore you

Depending on which of the above occurs will define your next steps.

Going off on your own and trying to enact organisational change, possibly without understanding why things are the way they are, and without the blessing of your manager is dangerous.

This is why a lot of other answers, while going into great detail about some idealized process, are dangerous.